# how create pagination with two statements?

Tags: php, pagination, statements

```
if(isset($_GET['cat'])){

        $categoryID = $_GET['cat'];

    $sql_getcatStock="SELECT * FROM stock where categoryID='$categoryID'";

         $query_getcatStock=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql_getcatStock);

         $count = mysqli_num_rows($query_getcatStock);

         if($count==0){
             echo "<h6>No Shops Found In This Category!</h6>";
         }

       while($rs_getcatStock=mysqli_fetch_array($query_getcatStock)){

           $name = $rs_getcatStock['name'];
           $stockID = $rs_getcatStock['stockID'];


           echo "

           <div class='block-inner'>


           <p><a href = 'details.php?Id=$stockID'>$name</a></p></div>";
       }
   }
```

I make link like this

```
<p><a href = 'details.php?Id=$stockID&page=$page'>$name</a></p>
```